# how to create new array using push method on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Im trying to create new array similar to  `myCourses` array using push method.

But somewhat it keeps log only one string at a time instead of creating a new similar array like `myCourses` array:

```js
let myCourses = ["Learn CSS Animations", "UI Design Fundamentals", "Intro to Clean Code"]
for (let i = 0; i < myCourses.length; i++) {
    let a = []
    a.push( a += myCourses[i] )
    console.log(a) 
}
```

Comment: Put `let a = []` before loop (now you redeclare `a` in every loop) and `a.push( myCourses[i] )` inside.

Comment: with this code `a += myCourses[i]`, what did you think you were getting?

Comment: You could just replace the whole code with `const a = Array.from(myCourses)`, or `const a = [...myCourses]`, or `const a = myCourses.slice()`. Or even `const a = myCourses.map(x => x)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to my comment above, the correct solution (if we accepted creating new array this way, using  for loop) is

```js
let myCourses = ["Learn CSS Animations", "UI Design Fundamentals", "Intro to Clean Code"]

// declare a only once
let a = []
for (let i = 0; i < myCourses.length; i++) {
    // a += myCourses[i] is non-sense in this case
    a.push( myCourses[i] )
}

console.log(a);
// write into console the result, just once, not in every loop 
// returns ["Learn CSS Animations", "UI Design Fundamentals", "Intro to Clean Code"]
```

Comment: Right to the point, thanks. the a += myCourses[i] is non-sense in this case cause the push method already do it

Comment: @tsurihe Glad to help you. `a+=myCourses[i]` is valid construction, should be used in the other cases, not here. Good luck in your next programming tasks!